# Freezing parts of neural net depending on classification label

Tags: neural-networks, classification, backpropagation

I have a classification model that is trained to predict the probability of approve/reject on an object, and we use the output of the final sigmoid as our final score to rank these object.

These objects have a high number of dimensions, so when a user rejects an object, we also ask for explicit reason why it was rejected i.e. (rejected, reason_X). My question is how do I incorporate this explicit signal into our model? We don't wait to wait for 100s of examples, with the same rejection reason, for the model to eventually adjust weights.

I had the following idea:

If an object's rejection reason corresponds to one of the features in the representation of the object (i.e. "object was too X"), we take that object and use it immediately in *training* the model. And since we explicitly know the problematic feature, we only keep that feature, and we "zero out" the other features - or somehow freeze the other input layers of the network.

The idea is to only backprop the paths corresponding to rejection reason/feature - but my concern is that artificially constraining the NN like this messes up its behavior.

Does this make sense or is there a better approach? Is there a name for this problem/solution?

---

If there would be a way to extend this to cases where we dont have an explicit feature that maps to the given reason, that would be even better - but maybe requires a separate post.